# Intel 8086 assembly, Trying to understand labels. Question

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I've been trying to understand some basic assembly principles, for a class. My professor proposed that we use TurboDebugger, which was made from borland back in the 80s. I write everything directly onto TD, as requested by my professor.

I'm trying to understand how to use labels in assembly. The code below was given by my professor as a guide. When I try to run anything that has to do with labels with characters like "start: " or " #start:", I get a symbol not found error. The comments were made by me for the sake of explaining my thought process.
Here's an imbgur album showing the GUI and the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zfmC.jpg

```
mov al,[0000]   //this loads the low byte of a with 0s
mov bl,[0001]   //this loads the low byte of b with 0001
cmp al,1        // it compares the al with the number 1
je continue     // jumps if equal to continue
jmp exit        //jumps to exit with no condition
continue:       // here as you can see, it uses a label
           cmp bl,2   //compares bl to number 2
           je ok_label  // jump if equal to 2, to ok_label
           jmp exit     // jumps to exit with no condition
ok_label:       //another label here
          mov [0000],00    //moves to ds point,0000 the number 00
          mov [0001],00    //moves to ds point,0001 the number 00
exit:            // another label.
```

my question is, I understand completely what this program does, BUT I cannot for the life of me figure  how i can assign labels with characters.

I'm obviously missing something. Any suggestions?Thanks in advance :D

Edited: As requested for clarity purposes.

Edit2: I've been studying all day, and best thing I could come up with, is when I need to use a Jump related function, I count how many "lines" i'll need and do it manually without the use of labels. Say for example I need to jump from cs:0100 to 3-4 lines ahead, I use something like jxx 0106. It's kind of a bummer, but it's the only solution I could come up with.

Comment: can you show a [mcve] of your attempt to use `start:`?  Because `start:` on a line by itself *is* valid syntax for a label, defining the symbol `start` which you can reference from other instructions.  What assembler are you using?  Copy/paste the exact shell command you ran to assemble this.

Comment: Ok so, I am using an assembler called TurboDebugger as I stated above, I run the assembler through the DOSBox emulator. On my code above, every line I wrote, is a different command I input in the command line, within the assembler. So a minial reproducible example would be just entering " continue" then hitting enter. I made an  SFW imgur album with the GUI and the such https://imgur.com/a/7OV0KWK

Comment: TD is only a debugger you can use on already-built binaries.  The modern equivalent is something like GDB, not a full IDE, I think.  The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_Debugger) says it sometimes shipped with Turbo Assembler.  Or are you interactively typing your code into the debugger?  I wouldn't be surprised if it can't define new labels.  Don't do that, use a separate assembler.

Comment: I am a huge noob and also I am interactively typing my code into the debugger, my professor said so. I've given my problem some thought. You reckon I could like assign  a " start " label to cs adress? Maybe that'd be the case? Also, I cannot ditch TD because the examination will require I type code there.

Comment: TurboDebugger is/was really an excellent piece of software. But I cannot recall to ever having set a label in it (other than breakpoints). The usual workflow was 1) coding => 2) assembling with TASM => 3) Debugging with TurboDebugger => Goto 1

Comment: Your professor wants you to develop code by typing it into a debugger?  That sounds insane.  When you're done you only have the machine code, not source with comments, right?  How did your professor teach you about labels?  If you have some working way to input the code in your question, do that for adding new labels to it.

Comment: I would be surprised if software from the 80s used C++ double slash //comments much less most current assemblers do not support that unless using a c compiler as an assembler (eewww).   some assembly languages (language is defined by the tool not the target) dont use colons, some do.  try a two or three line program hello:  nop b hello to resolve this....

Comment: The class is called Microcomputers and is divided into the theory part and the Lab portion. In the lab he taught us briefly on how to move around in the TD. Then basic functions like ADD,SUB,XCHG,MOV, the logic functions. Now in the curriculum we are doing data flow control (I translated the title, not sure if I did it correctly). So we are doing some comparisons. He has given us some written guides and we have to test it in the TD program. That's how the lesson goes. So as you can see, he wrote the code segment, I posted in my main question. And I had to test it out. Buuuuuut it didn't work.

Comment: @old_timer I added the comments for the sake of making a point. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Labels are used to tag some line of source code (for example to be able to write some sort of call yourlabel or goto mylabel. You write source code with a text editor. You should use a debugger to run and step inside the executing code where it is not the right place to edit the code.

Comment: The problem description in your question is really unclear.  I thought you were saying you had this working code and were trying to add a new `start:` label to it, since `start` isn't one of the labels defined by the code.  But according to your last comment, that's not the situation at all.  You're trying to type this code into TurboDebugger instead of into a text file for Turbo Assembler.  Are you sure you can't use TASM?  But anyway, [edit] your question to explain your situation more clearly.  What you're doing is not at all normal and requires description not buried in comments.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I fixed it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Good edit, now the question makes sense.  And yes, if you can't use labels, you need to count bytes of machine code, relative to the *end* of the jump instruction.  Note that x86 machine code is variable length; you can't just count instructions.  Many are not 2 bytes long.  (They can be anywhere from 1 to 15 bytes, with 1 to 5 bytes being very common.)  It's very inconvenient not to have labels, and means you have to adjust offsets of every jump if you add new instructions between it and its target.

Comment: So yeah, I figured what you said, and saw it happen. I was trying to count for a Jump function and the cs: values constantly changed. How should I tackle this issue? What should I read on? Any ideas?